# adding leading zero in r

Tags: r

my data set has codes which are supposed to be  5 digits. However, there are a few with 4 digits. I want to add leading zeros in front of those values with 4 digits. I used the following code:

```r
labos$postal1 <- sprintf("%05d", labos$postal)
```

This command added zeros in front of all the values, including those with 5 digits.

Help me add zeros just to the values with 4 digits.

Comment: Your command is working for me: `test <- c(1234,12345,12)`
`sprintf("%05d", test)` gives me `[1] "01234" "12345" "00012"`